# Appcall on function that uses global variables

Tags: ida

I'm reversing an executable, there is a function in the executable that uses global variables that are not used in any other function, they are initiated in the target function, My question is will Appcall work on these circumstances?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Appcall will work since it simply executes the function’s code.

However, the function itself may fail if the global state is not what it expects. So I suggest you to let the application run for a while so that the global data is initialized properly, pause it and then use Appcall.

Comment: I cannot run the code, its MBR code

Comment: @Req Appcall can be used only during debugging